# Finite difference in Haskell, or how to disable potential optimizations

Tags: optimization, haskell, numerical-methods, rounding-error

I'd like to implement the following naive (first order) finite differencing function:

```
finite_difference :: Fractional a => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
finite_difference h f x = ((f $ x + h) - (f x)) / h
```

As you may know, there is a subtle problem: one has to make sure that `(x + h)` and `x` differ by an exactly representable number. Otherwise, the result has a huge error, leveraged by the fact that `(f $ x + h) - (f x)` involves catastrophic cancellation (and one has to carefully choose `h`, but that is not my problem here).

In C or C++, the problem can be solved like this:

```
volatile double temp = x + h;
h = temp - x;
```

and the `volatile` modifier disables any optimization pertaining to the variable `temp`, so we are assured that a "clever" compiler will not optimize away those two lines.

I don't know enough Haskell yet to know how to solve this. I'm afraid that

```
let temp = x + h
    hh = temp - x 
in ((f $ x + hh) - (f x)) / h
```

will get optimized away by Haskell (or the backend it uses). How do I get the equivalent of `volatile` here (if possible without sacrificing laziness)? I don't mind GHC specific answers.

Comment: Why is sacrificing laziness an issue?

Comment: @Don: As a matter of fact, it's probably not. I plan to use this in rather contrived ways (eg. with Richardson extrapolation routines), in contexts where `h` would come from lazy infinite lists. But as far as this particular function is concerned, you are right, I did not think this straight (and I'm trying to get acquainted to the language).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have two solutions and a suggestion:

First solution: You can guarantee that this won't be optimized out with two helper functions and the NOINLINE pragma:

```
norm1 x h = x+h
{-# NOINLINE norm1 #-}

norm2 x tmp = tmp-x
{-# NOINLINE norm2 #-}

normh x h = norm2 x (norm1 x h)
```

This will work, but will introduce a small cost.

Second solution: Write the normalization function in C using volatile and call it through the FFI.  The performance penalty will be minimal.

Now for the suggestion: Currently the math isn't optimized out, so it will work properly at present.  You're afraid it will break in a future compiler.  I think this is unlikely, but not so unlikely that I wouldn't want to guard against it also.  So write some unit tests that cover the cases in question.  Then if it does break in the future (for any reason), you'll know exactly why.

Comment: I'm rather afraid that the LLVM backend will optimize the math (of course if given some "fast math" option I would like to enable, and disable just for those 2 lines). Volatile variables in C do the job, because there is a guarantee that the variable will be read from memory each time it is needed. But I don't want to write a C function since I need `Fractional a` (and not just `Double`) type. So writing a `NOINLINE` function (only one should suffice) *does* solve my problem.

Comment: NOINLINE works for the Haskell side. And the compilation strategy of GHC is such that LLVM or GCC *probably* won't see through the bindings to optimize the math in any unsafe way.

Comment: If the NOINLINE'd function is polymorphic and not exported, I have confidence that LLVM or GCC wouldn't see through it.  My suggestion for unit testing still stands though.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to look at the Core.

Specializing to `Doubles` (which will be the case most likely to trigger some optimization):

```
finite_difference :: Double -> (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double
finite_difference h f x = ((f $ x + hh) - (f x)) / h
   where
        temp = x + h
        hh   = temp - x
```

Is compiled to:

```
A.$wfinite_difference h f x =
    case f (case x of
                  D# x' -> D# (+## x' (-## (+## x' h) x'))
           ) of 
        D# x'' -> case f x of D# y -> /## (-## x'' y) h
```

And similarly (with even less rewriting) for the polymorphic version.

So while the variables are inlined, the math isn't optimized away.
Beyond looking at the Core, I can't think of a way to guarantee the property you want.

Comment: Yes, but that has the disadvantage that more aggressive optimisations could be introduced in future compiler versions. So a "black-box" way to prevent optimisations would be nice.

Comment: The only black box way is to add {-# GHC_OPTIONS -Onot #-}

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using GHC 7.02 and I bet the LLVM backend *will* optimize this out (there may be a "stick to IEEE math" option but I don't want to activate it for the whole library)

Comment: @Don: -Onot is quite aggressive. I just want to disable optimization for two specific lines.

Comment: Any kind of transformation the compiler does that does not respect the semantics of floating point numbers is a bug.  You should no have to do anything at all to get correct code.

Comment: @augustss: major C compilers have a switch to turn on an off "unsafe" math optimizations (ie. which do not respect FP semantics). Sometimes, this is what you want, and here, this is what you *don't* want. Sometimes I just want the compiler to assume that there will be no NaN, no infinities, and no denormalized numbers.

Comment: @Alexandre C: Yes, that's reasonable.  The LLVM code generator has an option to enable unsafe FP operations (in code generation, not optimization, AFAIK), but I doubt that ghc is able to convey things like NOINLINE to it.  So you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that

```
temp = unsafePerformIO $ return $ x + h
```

would get optimised out. Just a guess.